# groovy can Normal ternary operator preform more then one oparation?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

i have this Normal ternary operator but i like it to do more then 1 operation if false
for example :

```
def xxStr = x.x.1.1
    def ver = 0
    xxStr = (xxStr.contains('foo')) ? xxStr.replace('-foo','').tokenize('.') : xxStr.tokenize('.') && ver = xxStr.pop()
```

of coruse this not working as `xxStr.tokenize('.') && ver = xxStr.pop()`
is not ligal , but is there any elegant way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a block of code that can be executed at once.

One option (obviously) is to call a function that will execute all the operations:

```
def func() {
  println("no")
  println("definitely not")
}
(10 > 20) ? println ("yes") : func()
```

Another option is using closure:

```
​(10 > 20) ? println("yes") :  {​​​​​​​println("no"); println ("definitely not")​​​​​​​​​​​​}.call()
```

Both versions print:

```
no
definitely not
```

Comment: It does not answer OP's question. He asks for a use case, where the `true` branch of ternary operator assigns a single variable, and the `false` branch assigns two variables. Your `func()` does not assign any values, it just prints something to console.

Comment: Well, it was an example - I understood that the question was about executing multiple statements at once in a branch of ternary operator. Of course functions can get parameters, modify them and do whatever calculation they need, the same goes for closure. Apparently I've assumed that this can be done by OP him/herself.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `with` as in:

```
xxStr = xxStr.contains('foo') ? xxStr.replace('-foo','').tokenize('.') : xxStr.tokenize('.').with { pop() }
```

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator assigns value to a variable, thus you can't call assignment expression here. But there are more issues with the code you have presented. For instance:

```
xxStr.tokenize('.') && ver = xxStr.pop()
```

Expecting that `xxStr` after calling `xxStr.tokenize('.')` is a list is an misconception. The `xxStr` in this expression remains a `String` thus calling `pop` on it will throw `MissingMethodException`.

Forcing your code to be a one-liner does not mean you are using an elegant solution. In this case, I would say that it is the opposite. Also, you are using `def` in a dynamic context (you change the type from `String` to `List`). It is not prohibited, but in most cases, it only introduces confusion. It makes your code harder to understand and reason about.

I would strongly suggest diving the code into two separate sections: one responsible for tokenizing a string to an array, and second one responsible for popping the version. It makes your code more explicit and easier to understand. If there was a built-in easy-to-read solution in Groovy, you could consider using it. But adding this unnecessary level of abstraction to such a simple use case makes a very little sense.